# R: How to plot partially a raster on top of a map using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot parts of a raster (highest values) on top of a previously plotted map. Here my code:

```
ggplot() + geom_map(data = GERblue_iran, aes(map_id = state, fill = veggies), map = iran_states) + 
  expand_limits(x = iran_states$long, y = iran_states$lat) +      
  geom_polygon(data=iran_states, aes(x= long, y= lat, group=group), color='grey40', lwd=0.3, fill=NA) +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette="PuBu")
```

resulting in this plot:

[image]

And the code for the raster overlay:

```
ggplot() + geom_tile(data=nut_iran.df, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = layer)) + scale_fill_distiller(palette = "Reds")
```

[image]

My expected result should look (more or less) like this (result made in photoshop!!):

[image]

showing only values (of raster) above +/-1000.

Does anyone know how to plot like this in ggplot2?

For reproducibility, here a bit of my data:

```
library(ggplot2)
# polygons
iran <- getData("GADM", country = "IRN", level = 1)
iran_states <- fortify(iran, region = "NAME_1")

# data for choropleth map: 
GERblue_iran <- structure(list(veggies = c(NA, 1135142.7169744, 1064475.14405642, 
579007.139090945, 2291173.06203667, 1609487.86612194, 5514745.42173307, 
210033.193615536, NA, 1082275.82518455, 395053.664034339, 833546.886449334, 
1350410.79594876, 2030498.45168616, 5018327.9046678, 413119.296060151, 
853322.135586823, 2136776.14200603, 581494.047168068, 535593.624579909, 
414310.523642145, NA, NA, 2156369.86690811, 274390.590608389, 
546804.909031463, 144406.95766963, 285002.432443622, 1605244.30546598, 
307546.827903725, 589330.238261654), fruits = c(NA, 19645300.9396573, 
39318516.6693754, 15154130.3351692, 38374281.8287458, 29164989.9985857, 
125240289.719822, 6419392.00424945, NA, 23342736.5294504, 9223806.43987587, 
19008972.7788205, 62709223.291618, 41703691.9392781, 164306013.73773, 
13518682.0729514, 17420595.3934969, 44462391.2814304, 11715807.4374495, 
13475005.0070146, 12228946.6624824, NA, NA, 63708363.0757236, 
9221772.9477743, 13545791.4738047, 4268610.12809181, 6496251.74039526, 
31651316.7352119, 8570276.47057257, 10288282.5059752), nuts = c(NA, 
108771666.285736, 188713516.14938, 84626256.2539182, 227028948.551643, 
165167762.523232, 669060935.751113, 17905599.826691, NA, 124536243.958677, 
62369588.7036755, 123253859.776379, 3137384087.58166, 279956412.016931, 
506078060.03775, 70275261.7698334, 115596090.695869, 284469721.056207, 
73232219.7923014, 47691287.4633623, 73453936.1223698, NA, NA, 
382631908.316345, 78226462.4088062, 60449633.6571361, 25656409.607032, 
36523271.0224757, 233944364.555385, 158201233.377931, 74033085.0714528
), state = c("Alborz", "Ardebil", "Bushehr", "Chahar Mahall and Bakhtiari", 
"East Azarbaijan", "Esfahan", "Fars", "Gilan", "Golestan", "Hamadan", 
"Hormozgan", "Ilam", "Kerman", "Kermanshah", "Khuzestan", "Kohgiluyeh and Buyer Ahmad", 
"Kordestan", "Lorestan", "Markazi", "Mazandaran", "North Khorasan", 
"Qazvin", "Qom", "Razavi Khorasan", "Semnan", "Sistan and Baluchestan", 
"South Khorasan", "Tehran", "West Azarbaijan", "Yazd", "Zanjan"
)), .Names = c("veggies", "fruits", "nuts", "state"), row.names = c(NA, 
31L), class = "data.frame")
```

However, the raster data set is too large and I don't know how to make a random raster with this country extent. However, if someone knows how. Here is the transformation I did in order to plot it with `geom_tile()`:

```
nut_iran.spdf <- as(nut_iran, "SpatialPixelsDataFrame")
nut_iran.df <- as.data.frame(nut_iran.spdf)
```

Thanks for your ideas.

**EDIT:** I managed to plot as @spacedman suggested the raster as I want, setting all values in `nut_iran.df$layer` < 1000 into NAs. And plot them inculding `na.value="transparent"` to `scale_fill_distiller`. Result which is fine:

[image]

However, plotting both together delivers:

[image]

due to the 2 different fills (pointed by @hrbrmstr) the color are set to last colors (red) and the previous NA from the choropleth map are as well setted transparent.

Comment: Have you tried setting your raster cells that you want transparent to NA?

Comment: @Spacedman +1, but how is the OP going to do multiple legends/fills (the way they want to in the photoshopped version)?

Comment: @hrbrmstr when I have a full answer I'll post a full answer, but if setting values to NA makes the raster transparent then that's one thing sorted.

Comment: The tricky bit is creating a plot with two different `fill` scales...

Comment: Tried `package:tmap` as an alternative but rasters always seem to splat previous layers even with NA transparent pixels... bah...